# how to compare github pull request history using winmerge or other external toola?

Tags: git, github, winmerge

Though I like the in-built browser based comparison tool of github to compare pull request differences, i would like to use winmerge or any other external tool to compare differences between a pull request of another fork and master. how can i do it without adding the fork as a remote in my local repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git` operations are all locally, so you can't do the `diff` without adding it as a `remote`.

Just add it as a `remote`, `fetch` it, and then use `git difftool` to get the diff. If you don't need the remote after that, just `git remote rm` it and you're done!

Comment: guess thats my only option.. thinking to someow automate some of these repetetivet tasks part of this process.